# Calling a function after Bootstrap dropdown opened

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have found the following code to call a function upon the Bootstrap dropdown onclick event to open the menu. My problem is that I need to call my function *after* the dropdown div has actually opened. (I am measuring the width of the content but this can't be done until the HTML is on-screen). Can someone guide me how I could do some sort of *onready* event?

```
$('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () {
    doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The dropdown has a `shown.bs.dropdown` event that will fire after all transitions are complete: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events

```
$('.dropdown.data-api').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have scrolled down a bit on the Bootstrap page to see this. Still having trouble getting it working. Might post another question.

Comment: I've put up another post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904239/cant-get-bootstrap-dropdown-function-to-fire-after-open