# Can't get Bootstrap dropdown function to fire after open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've set up my code to run an alert upon the Bootstrap menu being opened, but I'm struggling to get the alert to fire.

```js
$('.dropdown.data-api').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
   alert('it worked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
     
    <span data-toggle="dropdown">Click me</span>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Hello World!
    </ul>
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event selector is looking for a dropdown with both `dropdown` and `data-api` classes. Either remove the `.data-api` from the event selector, or add `data-api` to the dropdown class list.

```js
$('.dropdown.data-api').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
   alert('it worked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown data-api">
     
    <span data-toggle="dropdown">Click me</span>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Hello World!
    </ul>
     
</div>
```